# Implementation of DBSCAN on PySpark not working

Tags: pyspark, dbscan

I am interested in using the `DBSCAN` algorithm on PySpark to cluster a set of features. I discovered a library called "pyspark-dbscan" that provides an implementation for this algorithm, which can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark-dbscan/1.0.5/#description). While I am aware that there are also implementations of DBSCAN in sklearn, my main focus is on utilizing this algorithm specifically with PySpark.

I run the example script from a page:

```
import dbscan
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from pyspark.sql import types as T, SparkSession
from scipy.spatial import distance

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("DBSCAN") \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.3-s_2.11") \
        .config('spark.driver.host', '127.0.0.1') \
        .getOrCreate()
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=750, centers=5, cluster_std=0.4, random_state=5)
data = [(i, [float(item) for item in X[i]]) for i in range(X.shape[0])]
schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("id", T.IntegerType(), False),
                               T.StructField("value", T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()), False)])
#please repartition appropriately                            
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema).repartition(10)
df_clusters = dbscan.process(spark, df, .2, 10, distance.euclidean, 2, "checkpoint")
```

As a result, I get the following errors:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
```

and

```
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Iterable; actual 2, expected 1
```

Has anyone had a similar problem using this library? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thank you in advance.